# How to make object from dictionary readable

Tags: python

I created a class `Demo` in which I added a constructor with an empty dictionary in it. With the method `addSomething` inside the class I add key value pairs to this dictionary. The key which gets added is of type `str` and the value of type `int`. In another method `useKeys` in the same class I wanna access the key which I added to the dictionary. With the `keys()` method I only get the key like `dict_keys([<__main__.Demo object at 0x7f7cd00c75b0>])`. How can I make the `str` who was added visible?

### Code

```py
class Demo:
    def __init__(self, someString):
        self.something = dict()

    def addSomething(self, something):
        if something not in self.something:
            self.something[something] = 0
        self.something[something] += 1

     def useKeys(self):
        #prints dict_keys([<__main__.Demo object at 0x7f7cd00c75b0>])
        print(self.something.keys())

something1 = Demo("ABC")
something2 = Demo("DEF")
something1.addSomething(something2)

print(something1.useKeys())
```

### Edit

One suggestion in the comments is to use `__str__`. I understand that this method gets called always if an object from this class gets printed. But how can I make the key from the dictionary readable? My current implementation does not make the key readable:

```py
def __str__(self):
        return "{self.something}".format(self=self)
```

Comment: override `__str__` and `__repr__`

Comment: As an separate method or can I call it somehow on it? @MZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With the method addSomething inside the class I add key value pairs to this dictionary. The key which gets added is of type str and the value of type int.

No, it is not. The key which gets added is of type `Demo` and the value is of type `int`. This is why printing the dictionary keys is printing the `__repr__` of a `Demo` object.

> How can I make the str who was added visible?

You did not add any `str`. The strings passed as arguments in your code are never used.

---

You can either write the `__repr__` function (which will override the `object` object function of the same name, from which every python3 class inherits), or you can use the argument `someString` you're already providing and that it's not being used at all, it's only forcing you to provide a string when creating a new instance of a `Demo` object:

### Solution 1

Actually using the attribute `someString` from the constructor in the `addSomething` function.

With this solution, the key is indeed of the type `str`.

```py
class Demo:
    def __init__(self, someString):
        self.something = dict()
        self.someString = someString # Actually using the string provided at instance time

    def addSomething(self, something):
        ## This method will use the attribute someString from object something instead
        if something.someString not in self.something:
            self.something[something.someString] = 0
        self.something[something.someString] += 1

    def useKeys(self):
        ## keys are now strings
        print(self.something.keys())

something1 = Demo("ABC")
something2 = Demo("DEF")
something1.addSomething(something2)

print(something1.useKeys())
```

### Solution 2

Overriding `__repr__`, but you require a string anyway so using `someString` from the constructor too.

With this solution, the key is of type `Demo`, but when you print that key, it'll display a string.

```py
class Demo:
    def __init__(self, someString):
        self.something = dict()
        self.someString = someString # Actually using the string provided at instance time

    def addSomething(self, something):
        ## This method will use the something object as in the original code
        if something not in self.something:
            self.something[something] = 0
        self.something[something] += 1

    def __repr__(self):
        ## When something1.__repr__ is called, it'll display the someString provided at instance time
        return self.someString

    def useKeys(self):
        ## keys are objects, but will appear as strings because of the __repr__ method from that object
        print(self.something.keys())

something1 = Demo("ABC")
something2 = Demo("DEF")
something1.addSomething(something2)

print(something1.useKeys())
```

The `__str__` function of an object is used in another circumstance, it's not needed in your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert it into a list for easy representation:

```
print(list(something1.useKeys()))
```

By the way, it does seem like the class you're implementing already exists as `collections.Counter`.

Comment: ```print(list(something1.useKeys()))``` throws ```TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable```

Comment: That's because you don't return the keys on useKeys